# python 2.7 loop's index in quotation marks

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I am using Python 2.7. How does you use the index of a loop inside quotation marks? This appears in a option. I have tried putting index in `quote()` and after `%`.

For example:

```
for i in range(1, 10):  
    parser.add_option('-l', '--location', value="i")
```

Comment: Why do you think you need quotation marks there?

Comment: Are you sure you need a string? It looks as though `value` can simply be integer valued. If not, `value=str(i)` should work as well. There are cases where you need to perform variable interpolation in a string literal, and there are ways to do it (see the posted answers), but this is not one of them.

Comment: It's just a toy example. Value is definitely a string as I'm concatenating it to other text later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [format option](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for strings.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    parser.add_option('-l', '--location', value="{0}".format(i))
```

To do something as simple as this, the better method would be

```
for i in range(1,10):
    parser.add_option('-l', '--location', value=str(i))
```

Comment: I just changed my original post to my actual question. I guess simplifying to print statement was over-simplification.

Comment: The same method works on any string, though there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print "This is the number {}".format(i)
```

Comment: Use of `%` for string formatting is discouraged in modern python code: http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple:

```
print "Number: %s" % 5
```

Comment: Use of `%` is discouraged in modern python code: http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: @MattBryant yes, but at the same time every Python programmer should know about it. Plus I think `printf` style formatting is too ubiquitous for even BDFL to rid the world of it entirely. So +1.